# spark shuffle read time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, shuffle

[image]k.imgur.com/r8NIv.png

[image]

I am having hard time processing this information from Spark UI. The executor which has lowest spark shuffle read size/Records takes maximum time to read the shuffle blocks as shown in the pictures. I am not understanding if this is a code issue or if this is a data node issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it not only caused by the shuffle read size,there are many factors affecting the shuffle time like the number of partitions.You can try to modify the configuration parmeters about shuffle.
[shuffle-behavior](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#shuffle-behavior)